# Nested Divs with the same name, select the correct one one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where I have nested divs with the same class. For instance I have something like Panel, inside of Panel. However, when I click on the panel inside the first panel, it is the first panel that triggers the

```
 $(".panel").click
```

function. However, I need to somehow drill down to the panel which the mouse actually clicked on. In other words if I had the following code:

```
 <div class="panel"> //first panel
      <div class="panel"> //second panel
      </div>
 </div>
```

When I want the second panel to trigger the click, I instead get the parent panel triggering the click. This makes sense given the second panel is wrapped in the first panel. However, I was wondering if there is a way around this? In theory, the code that I am writing can have an infinite ammount of panels inside of other panels. Is there a way to drill all the way down to the panel that the mouse has clicked on? (not the containing panel)

EDIT:

Here is the entire code segment:

```
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    height: 700px;

}
.gridSegment
{
            width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    outline: 2px solid black;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastID = 10;
     $(".gridSegment").dblclick(function(){
         console.log($(this).attr("ID"));
         lastID++;
         $(this).append("<div class='gridSegment' id='" + lastID + "'></div>");
         lastID++;
         $(this).append("<div class='gridSegment' id='" + lastID + "'></div>");
         lastID++;
         $(this).append("<div class='gridSegment' id='" + lastID + "'></div>");
         lastID++;
         $(this).append("<div class='gridSegment' id='" + lastID + "'></div>");
         return false;

     });
});
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class='gridSegment'>
        <div class='gridSegment' id ="1"></div>
        <div class='gridSegment' id ="2"></div>
        <div class='gridSegment' id ="3"></div>
        <div class='gridSegment' id ="4"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: do these div's have any parent?? like in `DIV`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of changing your code slightly (just for the example). Mainly the loops and I also changed the `id` attributes to add a little more information - you can now see exactly what level you are in.  If you feel it suites your needs then by all means you can adopt it into your application.

You mentioned in a comment that the `.live()` function solves your problem, however this feature is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and it is recommended to use the `delegate()` function in place of `live()` if you can't use `on()`.  So here is my solution using the `delegate()` function.

As you can see the syntax is similar only that we attach the callback to the container element and specify what internal selector to use - in our case it is any `.gridSegment` element.

```
$("#body").delegate(".gridSegment", "dblclick", function() {
     var $thisCached = $(this);
     console.log($thisCached,$(this).parent());
     var lastId = $thisCached.attr("id");
     var limit = 4;
     var counter = 1;
     while(counter <= limit){
       var newId = lastId + '_' + counter;
       counter++;    
       $thisCached.append("<div class='gridSegment' id='" + newId + "'></div>");         
     }
     return false;
});
```

**Note that my wrapper is an *element* with the id of body**

#### [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wCLZR/9/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, putting the elements I have inserted into loops is necessary as well as providing extra information; I just had quickly drafted code to, well what I thought, quickly prototype the idea. Thank you very much for your help, I hope more people on this site would go out of their way like you do including myself! Its too bad all I can give you is an upvote and check off your answer! I hope to see you around this site again (hopefully next time I could help you out)!

Comment: you are most welcome :P  an up vote or accept is all the thanks I need :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Check out this [example on jsFiddle (open your JavaScript console)](http://jsfiddle.net/wCLZR/1/)
>   *(please excuse the ugly colors - I'm a programmer not a designer ;).*

```
$(function(){
    $('.panel').on('click',function(e){
       console.log($(this));
       return false;
    });
});​
```

All you have to do is return false when you capture the click to stop the event bubbling back up to the containing element.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. It seems the execution order of the click is top down not down up. In other words as soon as I click, it simply sees the wrapping panel and stops there. It returns me the same panel (I've assigned IDs) which is the parent panel.

Comment: Could you possibly update your post with some more code that you are using?  As you can see from the jsFiddle example I posted, this should work...

Comment: I have posted the rest of the code. It seems like when the Jquery adds in the new grid segments, the code solution that you have presented no longer works for some reason...

Comment: Ah.. .dynamically added elements... No problem :)  See my updates... Just change `click()` to `on('click')`

Comment: and this is why I much prefer back-end web development to front end web development. I feel like I waste a lot of time fixing bugs that just need to be "worded differently".

Comment: Unfortunately .on('dblclick',function() {.. has the same issue as before :(

Comment: I guess the computer science way to do this is to return the stack of elements clicked on and simply invoke the top one. Let me see if that works...

Comment: I just noticed that you are using number only `id` attributes.  Can you try using an `id` value that doesn't start with a number? Can you try changing them to `a1,a2,a3,...`.  I find that number only id's tend to cause problems...

Comment: Same issue. It seems like the dynamic content is being ignored and automatically bubbles up to the non-dynamic. I have tried adding event.stopPropagation(); but it unfortunately does not help.

Comment: Thank you very much for sticking around to help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: One of the solutions described is to add: 
if(event.target != this){
  return true;
}
But the issue is that the propagation stops after that which is very strange... They are inside that div tag 100%

Comment: Found the solution. Use .live() instead of .on(). On() doesn't seem to link the event handler to the new element properly. Throw up the answer so I can give you credit. I really appreciate you sticking around to help and you deserve the credit.

Comment: Using `live()` is really discouraged... `"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated."`.. I'll see if I can't get to the bottom of this...

Comment: I've added an additional solution - it might be better than using the deprecated `live()` function...

Answer (score 0):

Use id's

```
<div class="panel" id="panel_1">
    <div class="panel" id="panel_2">
...
```

or use data-* attributes

```
<div class=panel data-pid=1>
```

then

```
$('.panel').click(function(){
   alert('panel id is: '+$(this).attr('data-pid'));
})
```